# Div with diagonal sides for parallax animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, parallax

How to make two diagonal divs for scrolling parallax animation?  I need slide transition like here on the six item(bullet) https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/INT, but with diagonal sides.

Comment: what is a diagonal div?

Comment: div with diagonal left&right sides =)

Comment: ok, then what is a diagonal side? Do you mean a div that has a form of a trapezoid?

Comment: yes, it's what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Well... there's no such thing as a diagonal div. But you could rotate them to make it seem diagonal. You can do it with CSS 3 and rotation transform

see this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

and an example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_rotate

sample code:

```
#myDIV
{
    transform:rotate(10deg);
}
```

PERSONAL NOTE: I think that your approach should be the use of a "normal" div with a "diagonal" background image and making the contents of your div appearing with some animation dependding of your scroll position to create the illusion that you are in fact using a diagonal div

**UPDATE 1:** Here are a couple of links that I think will be of your interest

- http://unfold.no/
- http://harvestcreative.com/
- http://www.nike.com/jumpman23/aj2012/

**UPDATE 2**: Another cool thing: http://www.css3shapes.com/